# How to add values in an array inside an array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array

I apologize if my title sounds so confusing, as I don't know how to exactly word it. Basically, this is what I'm trying to do.

For example, I have the following array:

```
var sourceArray = [
     { question: "Question 1", inputType: "radio", answer: "Answer 1", id: "1" },
     { question: "Question 1", inputType: "radio", answer: "Answer 2", id: "2" },
     { question: "Question 1", inputType: "radio", answer: "Answer 3", id: "3" },
     { question: "Question 2", inputType: "radio", answer: "Answer 1", id: "4" },
     { question: "Question 2", inputType: "radio", answer: "Answer 2", id: "5" },
     { question: "Question 2", inputType: "radio", answer: "Answer 3", id: "6" }
]
```

I want to restructure this so that it'll look like this:

```
var newArray = [
     {
      question: "Question 1", inputType: "radio", 
      choices: [{answer: "Answer 1", id: "1"},
                {answer: "Answer 2", id: "2"},
                {answer: "Answer 3", id: "3"}
               ]},
     {
      question: "Question 2", inputType: "radio", 
      choices: [{answer: "Answer 1", id: "4"},
                {answer: "Answer 2", id: "5"},
                {answer: "Answer 3", id: "6"}
     ]}
]
```

Answers are grouped by question, so if the next question in the `sourceArray` is the same with the current, it will push the answers into the `choices` array.

Is this possible in AngularJS using angular.forEach?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you as always for your responses.

Comment: Could you post a plunker on how far you have accomplished to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. See the working example below:

```js
// Add a hepler method in the Array to find the value
Array.prototype.find = function(key, value) {
  var index = -1;
  angular.forEach(this, function(item, i) {
    if (item[key] === value) {
      index = i;
    }
  });

  return this[index];
};

var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {

  $scope.sourceArray = [{
    question: "Question 1",
    inputType: "radio",
    answer: "Answer 1",
    id: "1"
  }, {
    question: "Question 1",
    inputType: "radio",
    answer: "Answer 2",
    id: "2"
  }, {
    question: "Question 1",
    inputType: "radio",
    answer: "Answer 3",
    id: "3"
  }, {
    question: "Question 2",
    inputType: "radio",
    answer: "Answer 1",
    id: "4"
  }, {
    question: "Question 2",
    inputType: "radio",
    answer: "Answer 2",
    id: "5"
  }, {
    question: "Question 2",
    inputType: "radio",
    answer: "Answer 3",
    id: "6"
  }];

  $scope.newArray = [];

  $scope.convert = function() {
    // Iterate array
    angular.forEach($scope.sourceArray, function(item) {
      // Check if the question alrady exists
      if (!$scope.newArray.find('question', item.question)) {
        // If not, push the question to the array with empty choices
        $scope.newArray.push({
          question: item.question,
          inputType: item.inputType,
          choices: []
        });
      }

      var newArrayItem = $scope.newArray.find('question', item.question);
      
      // Push the choices
      newArrayItem.choices.push({
        answer: item.answer,
        id: item.id
      });
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController">
  Before:
  <br>{{sourceArray | json}}
  <br>
  <a href="" ng-click="convert()">convert</a>
  <br>After:
  <br>{{newArray | json}}
</div>
```

Comment: Good approach. Liked.

Comment: You are a lifesaver, Shashank. This worked wonderfully. Thank you!

Comment: Glad this worked!! The main goal you understand the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can group together using a for loop,

Here is the code:

```
function transformArr(orig) {
    var newArr = [],
        answers = {},
        newItem, i, j, cur;
    for (i = 0, j = orig.length; i < j; i++) {
        cur = orig[i];
        if (!(cur.question in answers)) {
            answers[cur.question] = {question: cur.question, answers: [],inputType : cur.inputType,id :cur.id};
            newArr.push(answers[cur.question]);
        }
        answers[cur.question].answers.push(cur.answer);
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

Working [`App`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/nSLua/96/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `filter` in the `sourceArray`, the two *Questions List* as below:

```
var question1 = $filter('filter')(sourceArray, {
  question: 'Question 1'
});
var question2 = $filter('filter')(sourceArray, {
  question: 'Question 2'
});
```

After that, you should create a new data of array as below:

```
$scope.questionData = [{
  "question": "Question 1",
  "inputType": "radio",
  "choices": []
}, {
  "question": "Question 2",
  "inputType": "radio",
  "choices": []
}];
```

Then, you should run loops over the two filtered a variables into the new Array of object:

1):

```
angular.forEach(question1, function(value, key) {
  if (value.question == $scope.questionData[0].question) {
    $scope.questionData[0].choices.push({
      'answer': value.answer,
      'id': value.id
    });
  }
});
```

2):

```
angular.forEach(question2, function(value, key) {
  if (value.question == $scope.questionData[1].question) {
    $scope.questionData[1].choices.push({
      'answer': value.answer,
      'id': value.id
    });
  }
});
```

Refer here for [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/xq2nku69/):